# Angular firebase Second subscribe on Observable from snapshotChanges() dont work

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my upload.service which is provided by upload.module. When I am using it in upload.component it works fine :

```
export class UploadsListComponent implements OnInit {

  uploads: Observable<Upload[]>;
  showSpinner = true;

  constructor(private upSvc: UploadService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploads = this.upSvc.getUploads();
    console.log("upload list upload :")
    this.uploads.subscribe(() => this.showSpinner = false);
  }
}
```

Upload.component.html :

```
<div *ngFor="let upload of uploads | async">
  <upload-detail [upload]='upload'></upload-detail>
  <img src="{{upload.url}}" alt="">
</div>
```

**When I am using it in another modules component upload.url is null.**

**The function which I think is bad:**

```
 uploads: Observable<Upload[]>;

getUploads() {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(`${this.auth.userId}`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
       const $key = a.payload.key;
       return { $key, ...data };
      });

    });
    return this.uploads;
  }
```

**Why upload.url only shows once ?**

Photo explanation : 
[image]

Note: dont look at console it has some errors that doesnt matter and some bad console.log